# How to call all Custom Directive globally instead of calling each component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, directive

I'm setting up a directive for my Vue project on separate individual files.

So far I have succeeded separating files and calling it globally but only possible to do it individually instead of exporting the entire directive and make it global.

```
**directive.js
const highlight ={
    bind(el, binding, vnode) {
       ... some code
}

const highlight2 ={
    ... some code
}
export default {
    highlight,
        highlight
}
```

```
**main,js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import * as directive from './directive.js'

Vue.directive(directive);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  directive
})
```

so far I have been able to call this directive on my main.js but stuck on how to make it globally without calling every single component. like

```
import { highlight, highlight2} from './directive
```

Edit:
Found my way by looping through with forEach function.

```
Object.keys(directive).forEach(function(name){
    Vue.directive(name, directive[name])
})
```

Comment: What are you using to build your Vue app? For example, if you're using Webpack, you can [provide a plugin globally](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/).

Comment: I'm using the standard webpack build. I already found the way though as mentioned above.